# How to create a table with 100% width, with dynamic width for the 1st column, and wrapped text in the 2nd column?

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to format the debug log of an app as an HTML table. I have two columns: one for time stamps, and one for the text of log entries. The text can easily contain long character sequences. Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="ts">12:50:01.683</td>
        <td class="txt">[1]: NDIS-WDM_Driver_for_HighSpeed_USB-Ethernet_Adapter_(Microsoft's_Packet_Scheduler)_:\Device\NPF_{7D9F4819-8B81-49FA-B321-5F1ACBD6740D}</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ts">12:50:01.683</td>
        <td class="txt">[2]: Realtek_10/100/1000_Ethernet_NIC_________________________________(Microsoft's_Packet_Scheduler)_:\Device\NPF_{90EF96D0-AC16-41E5-AFFD-1B25D439A0D9}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="ts">12:50:01.683</td>
        <td class="txt">[3]: Realtek_10/100/1000_Ethernet_NIC_________________________________(Microsoft's_Packet_Scheduler)_:\Device\NPF_{D3FA28DC-C59B-4027-AC43-6480B775ACD9}</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like the table to always use 100% browser width. The width of the time stamp column should adapt to its content, and the text of the second column should wrap automatically. The CSS I tried:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td { 
    border: solid 1px #000;
}

.ts {
    width: 100px;
}

.txt {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

In Chrome 26, without `table-layout: fixed;`, the table is wider than the browser, and a horizontal scroll bar appears. Since this setting makes the width of my columns equal, I had to set the width of the time stamp column to a predefined value: `width: 100px;`.

The problem is, if the user changes the zoom factor by `Ctrl + Mouse Wheel`, timestamps can easily become wider than their column, which looks ugly. Is it possible to make the width of the timestamp column follow the width of its content? (I could make it unbreakable with `white-space: pre;`.) Or, is there another approach which is not based on `table-layout: fixed;`?

Comment: If I `Ctrl + Mouse Wheel` in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7KvEg/) using Chrome 26 the timestamps will fit in their column just fine?

Comment: @Jeroen Try to set 50% zoom.

Comment: Looks fine to me? [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/floVBom.png).

Comment: @Jeroen In my browser: http://i.imgur.com/KUfdGSW.jpg

Comment: o.O I see. This depends on the font, it seems, I get similar results with Georgia at 67% zoom. Seems like a browser-specific problem with font rendering then.

Answer (score 0):

Since `1em` is equal to the current font size, it's better to set the width of the time stamp column in `em` units instead of `px`. This way the width of the column will be proportional to its content, which solves the zooming problem.

This solution is sub-optimal because the actual width value will depend on the `font-family`. For example for `Times New Roman`, the width of the time stamp column can be set to `6em`, but a wider font like `Courier New` requires `8em`.